# Symfony 2 : Starting with FOSCommentBundle

Tags: symfony, comments

I installed FOSCommentBundle (after installing JMSSerializerBundle and FOSRestBundle) by following the instructions of the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).

But when I try to apply what is written on the [last page of the tutorial](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/4-enable_comments_on_a_page.md), nothing happens on the generated page (nothing is displayed where I included async.html.twig), whereas I didn't forget to include jQuery. In the database, an entry with "foo" id key is created in the Thread table (as written in the async.html.twig code).

Moreover, I absolutely don't know how to use this bundle. I didn't find plenty of tutorials about it (like with FOSUserBundle), and the documentation does not contain a "Starting with" section. I don't know exactly what are Thread(s)/Comment(s), how they are linked together, what are the meanings of the different fields in these classes, what are the methods/views to use to post/display comments, ...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

ok fine , make sure that `comments.js` include properly on page

```
fos_comment_script.src = '{{ asset('path to js/comments.js') }}';
```

if `thread id` is not set, it will create automaticaly